# How to write to a file which is open?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am writing my script's output to an Excel file using [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), which is working fine. However, if the Excel file is accidently open while Python is trying to write to it, it shows a `PermissionError`- which is expected. On this case, what I would have preferred is to write somehow rather than showing the error. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Does https://superuser.com/questions/491020/how-do-i-prevent-excel-from-locking-files-by-default help?

Comment: It is not advised to write to an open file.

Comment: I am using windows 10

Comment: What's wrong with the exception? It seems the write thing here and gives **you** the chance to do something about it, such as close the file in Excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really solve this because the problem is not with `openpyxl` per-se, rather with the file you manually opened. ***If you would have opened it as a Read-Only file, you will not get that error***. Of course, you can't (easily) solve that programmatically as `openpyxl` is not aware of the open instances of Excel you have running in the background.

***Note*** that when opening the file as read-only, you will not see the saved changes from `openpyxl`.

One possible workaround, to avoid losing your changes you were about to save, is to allow the user to close that instance of Excel and try to save again. Something like:

```py
while True:
    try:
        wb.save(path)
    except PermissionError:
        input(f"Please close the excel {path} and press Enter")
    else:
        print(f"Excel file saved successfully at - {path}")
        break
```

Alternatively save to a temporary file and let the user merge later:

```py
from pathlib import Path

try:
    wb.save(path)
except PermissionError:
    path = Path(path)
    temp_path = path.with_name(f"{path.stem}_temp{path.suffix}")
    wb.save(temp_path)
    print(f"Excel file saved temporarily at - {temp_path}")
else:
    print(f"Excel file saved successfully at - {path}")
```

***Warning:*** these might cover-up other possible `PermissionError`s, so use with care.

Comment: I followed the logic that there should be no error if the file is opened for reading only but I still get the same error `[Errno 13] Permission denied`
`temp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode="r")`
`workbook.save(temp_file.name)`

Comment: @VladTkach Well, it seems you created a temporary file in read mode. You can't write to that. When I said to open the file as read only i meant opening the excel file for view ***in Excel***, not through Python